# Interpreting human speech

Tags: speech-recognition, interaction

I'm creating a home automation system, and want to make it "smarter" by interpreting human speech in a natural way, in order to control household objects, read the news, etc.

How should I go about converting a string input (I already have some working recognition libraries) into executable commands?

I need a way to communicate with my system like a would with a fellow human, and if this is impossible, something close. I don't expect it to be able to show emotion, or talk to it about my day, but simply command to to do things in a normal way.

I can upload the source to my current project if anyone asks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is essentially a command shell. You could set up a list of actions and then implement a shell to parse the action and the object to perform it on.

Each command would have the structure

```
<action> <param1> <param2> ...
```

For e.g.,

```
read news
read news sports
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, and that is basically what I have already. But I want the speaking to seam more natural than that, and be able to say things like "Turn on my air conditioning for twenty minutes", and "What will the weather be like tomorrow?" Obviously I can't have a command for each possibility, since there are so many. I know this seems like a daunting task, but I have a lot of free time on my hands.

Comment: That makes it a lot tougher. A lot of natural language processing would be involved. You can try looking around for "Natural Language Command Line". That would point you in the right direction.
Although I'd warn you, this is a very tough problem you're looking at. I planned to do something similar last year with web actions (upload to Dropbox, post to FB, etc.) and approached my NLP professor and she advised me that without restricting the domain to a certain set of action, it would be very hard to implement anything.